# Python: AttributeError while reading images with PIL library

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to work on a set of images using PIL library. I have no problems with importing images, but then, when I try to access size information of the first image from the list I receive an error. Function:

```
def loadImages(path):

    image_path = listdir(path)
    image_list = []
    for img in image_path:
        image = Image.open(path + img)
        image_list.append(image)

    return image_list

path = 'path/to/images'

images = loadImages(path)
N = len(images)
print("Number of images:", N)

w,h= Image.open(images[0]).size
```

And the whole error list:

```
  File "<ipython-input-42-502dda9bf243>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/mosaicing/vignetting/alphatrim_vs_distance.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/mosaicing/vignetting')

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/mosaicing/vignetting/alphatrim_vs_distance.py", line 39, in <module>
    w,h= Image.open(images[0]).size

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2557, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)

AttributeError: 'MpoImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I am working on:
pillow 5.0.0
python 3.6.4

Comment: As a point of style, your `loadImages` could be a list comprehension: `[Image.open(path + img) for img in listdir(path)]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to open the image twice. Once in `loadImage` and then you try to open what `Image.open` returns (which is already an image) later when you do:

```
w,h = Image.open(images[0]).size
```

Because `images[0] = Image.open(path + listdir(path)[0])`, you are effectively doing the following with the above line:

```
w,h = Image.open(Image.open(path + listdir(path)[0])).size
```

You should just be able to do:

```
w, h = images[0].size
```